# GroupBy performs slowly

Tags: c#

I have the following query and is super slow for 3000 records and produces 370 entries. How can I improve performance on it?

```
dealerResults = _results.GroupBy(x => new { x.DealerName, x.DealerId })
                                      .Select(x => new MarketingReportResults()
                                      {
                                          DealerId = x.Key.DealerId,
                                          DealerName = x.Key.DealerName,
                                          LinkedTotal = linkedLeadCores.Count(y => y.DealerId == x.Key.DealerId),
                                          LeadsTotal = x.Count(),
                                          SalesTotal = x.Count(y => y.IsSold),
                                          Percent = (decimal)(x.Count() * 100) / count,
                                          ActiveTotal = x.Count(y => y.IsActive),
                                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: How large is `linkedLeadCores`?

Comment: Is it `IQueryable<>` or `IEnumerable<>` ?

Comment: What is `_results`, is it another query? Is `linkedLeadCores` a collection or a database table? If it's a table, is there an index on `DealerId`? Too many things unclear.

Comment: Is the data in a database?  If so offload the query to the Db sever.  There's no comparing the performance of something optimised for data manipulation to something else (linq) designed as a sub-utility for manipulating small datasets in memory (i.e. there's pretty much zero internal query optimisation)

Comment: Might remove Grouping and see if that cause performance reduction, might see SQL Query - and use SQL Server Profiler to detect bottleneck ... etc. Many ways, many reasons possible - for example if you use Azure SQL with the Pricing Tier Basic - it won`t be fast for sure.

Comment: linkedLeadCores is an IEnumerable<> with 1661 items,  _results is a List with 3000 Objects,  dealerId, DealerName are properties in the _results object,  All this data is not from the database, they are all lists

Comment: i have just commented out  //LinkedTotal = linkedLeadCores.Count(y => y.DealerId == x.Key.DealerId), inside the Select and it group 3000 items in a split second,  how can l improve that logic?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the `linkedLeadCores.Count()` is the bottleneck here as you loop though the entire `linkedLeadCores` list each time a entry of `_results` is processed. This assumption seems to be confirmed by your comments also.

So to remove the bottleneck you could create a map (aka dictionary) that holds the count for each dealer before doing anything with `_results` like this ...

```
var linkedLeadCoresCountMap = linkedLeadCores
    .GroupBy(y => y.DealerId )
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Count());
```

... and then you could write

```
LinkedTotal = linkedLeadCoresCountMap.ContainsKey(x.Key.DealerId) ?
    linkedLeadCoresCountMap[x.Key.DealerId] : 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to `linkedLeadCores` will use an internal hash table for lookup and should solve your problem.

```
var dealerResults = 
               (from r in _results.GroupBy(x => new { x.DealerName, x.DealerId })
               join llc in linkedLeadCores on r.Key.DealerId equals llc.DealerId into g
               select new MarketingReportResults()
               {
                  DealerId = r.Key.DealerId,
                  DealerName = r.Key.DealerName,
                  LinkedTotal = g.Count(),
                  LeadsTotal = r.Count(),
                  SalesTotal = r.Count(y => y.IsSold),
                  Percent = (decimal)(r.Count() * 100) / count,
                  ActiveTotal = r.Count(y => y.IsActive),
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this make the process to be instant. Thank you guys